# Using file geodatabase with HTML in attribute column?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, html

I am working with a file geodatabase (.gdb) where one of the attribute columns contains html code:

[image: Screenshot of Attribute Table in ArcGIS]

My issue is that the attributes that I need are embedded in the html code. The screenshot below shows a "Prj_type" field with a value of "Sediment Diversion" for the highlighted feature. I need a "Prj_Type" column that would have a value of "Sediment Diversion" for this feature:

[image: Screenshot of Attribute Table after Exported to Excel]

(The attribute table viewer in ArcGIS only shows the first line, so I exported the table to Excel to see the full html code.)

Is there a way to parse the html in this attribute column to create new columns based of the fields and values in the html?

Comment: I would use ArcPy cursors to do this.

Comment: Thank you. I've never used ArcPy and have limited experience with python. How would this approach work?

Comment: See if you can use a `SearchCursor` to `print` your data first, then move to using an `UpdateCursor` and Python string manipulation to strip out the bits you need and write them to another field.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not comfortable in Python but love Excel, you could export out that field and an id field you could join with later. Then in Excel, find/replace, Mid, Left, Right functions to rip it apart and place it in new correct fields, then join back to your featureclass and drop the html field.